# How to search values in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a big csv files with the following format:

CSV FILE 1

```
id, person,   city
1,   John,     NY
2,   Lucy,    Miami
3,   Smith,   Los Angeles
4,   Mike,    Chicago
5,   David,   Los Angeles
6,   Daniel,    NY
```

On another CSV file I have each city with a numerical code:

CSV FILE 2

```
city , code
NY   ,  100
Miami,  101
Los Angeles, 102
Chicago, 103
```

What I need to do is go through CSV File 1 in the city column, read the name of the city and get the numerical code for that city from CSV File 2. I could then just output that list of city codes to a text file. For this example I would get this result:

```
100
101
102
103
102
100
```

I used csv.DictReader to create dictionaries for each file but I am stuck trying to find a way to map each city to each code.

Any ideas or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: @robert I'm kind of embarrased to say that I haven't actually done much because I got stuck immediately after reading CSVFile1 and creating the dictionary. I had no idea how to go on from there. I read the python manual on the site but could not find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have some extra whitespace there, and unlike some storage formats, CSV does care about it. If that is actually in your source data, you may have to strip it out before it will be processed as you expect (otherwise various fields will have leading and trailing whitespace).

Assuming that the whitespace is gone, however, it's fairly straightforward to do. You can just create a dictionary mapping names to codes, based on the contents of your second file.

```
from csv import DictReader

city_codes = {}
for row in DictReader(open('file2.csv', 'rb')):
    city_codes[row['city']] = row['code']

for row in DictReader(open('file1.csv', 'rb')):
    print city_codes[row['city']]
```

Naturally, you can send this out to a text file as you wish, simply by redirecting the output of print as you usually would.

Comment: This worked great! But I don't actually understand what the `city_codes ...` part after opening file2.csv is doing?

Comment: The `city_codes` dictionary is intended to map city names to codes. That line adds a new entry, whose key is the city of the current row, and whose value is the code of the current row. We can later use this entry to look up the code given the city name.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Jeremy suggested, you could use the string method .strip() to remove the trailing and leading whitespace automatically.

Comment: The caveat to this is that DictReader will end up including the whitespace in the keys of all of your row dictionaries. Avoiding this means preprocessing the file before DictReader gets to see it, or stripping the keys of each and every row. It's a bit ugly, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using sqlite3. You can then do efficient, simple and powerful joins.
If files are really big, you can benefit from creating proper index.

Comment: Yes, since I've actually worked a bit with databases before this seemed like a natural db application for me. But I haven't worked with DBs in python yet.